# How can I get Notepad++ to remember an installed language?

Tags: installation, notepad++

I have installed a language style in Notepad++ which the company I work for developed. When I open a certain file, one which I wish to use this defined language on, every time I open it I have to manually select what language I wish to use.

How do I make Notepad++ remember what language to use for certain extensions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `settings` -> `Style configurator` and in that choose the installed language.

In the `User ext` text box at the bottom add your extensions. If you want multiple file extensions - use space as a delimiter

---

**Edit**

After your comment I realized that it was not a plugin but just one of those .xml files notepad allows.

In this case go to `Language` > `Define your language ...` and select your custom language in the dropdown on the top left. Now find the textbox for `Ext. :` - i'll be somewhere around the top right. Add the extension you wish to associate with this language.

---

**Note**: do NOT type `.abc` - only the extension should be added - so, to open `test.abc` using this language definition by default, type `abc` here

Comment: great. thanks. the file extension mine is '  .template  ' so where it has 'Ext. : ' i have .template not just template, that was the problem :)))) thank you :)